# Google DataStudio how to make Pie from two filtered Scorecards?

Tags: looker-studio

I tried everything and it's not possible or i don't know how to make it.

I have event-action lets say "color"

This event-action has data containing different labels and it contains  rather  "black" or "white" text in the label.

I made  1 filter to extract the total number of blacks  and 1 more filter  to get the total number of whites.

**How to show in my Data Studio  a Pie with  how many *% include black* and how many include white in the labels? 
Is it possible to blend data between 2 filter results?**

Answer (score 0):

The method you a trying can't be used as pie charts can only have one metrics. You could possibly manage that with a stacked bar chart?

If "event-action" can't include black AND white then create a dimension with a case statement along the lines of:

```
CASE 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(event-action,"black") THEN "black"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(event-action,"white") THEN "white"
ELSE "other"
END
```

You can then use this (filtering out the "other" if necessary) as the dimension in the pie chart with a suitable sum/count metric.